# Android Java Recurring notifications best practice

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarm, recurring

The feature I want to achieve is basically that I want my app to send 1-3 notifcations each day, every day, at approximate times. For example, one notification between 09:00-11:00, one between 13:00-18:00 and one between 20:00 and 22:00.

I started off by trying to use setRepeating from alarmManager, I didn't get this to work at all, maybe I used it wrong. I then moved to a solution to schedule a new notification every time the app is started, or each time a notification is received.

It works somewhat, since the otification is schedule during onCreate the notifications are sent and received ok as long as I sometimes open the app. And some of them are re-scheduled properly even without opening the app. But it seems like they "disappear" after a while of not opening the app, as if the notifications stops getting sent. I have tried removed battery optimization, didn't resolve the issue.

Are there some best practices for handling recurring notifications? I know some apps have issues with notifications not being send, for example Telegram on my phone. But some are working flawlessly, for example Duolingo.

Some of the code:

In the onCreate(), I check permission (or ask permission) and then call the schedule function:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Notification.scheduleNotification(context);
    }
} else {
    Notification.scheduleNotification(context);
}
```

The function that schedules the notification:

```
private static final int[] notificationHours = {8,15,20,22};

public static int nextAlarmHour(int currentHour) {
    // Find the next alarm hour that is greater than the current hour
    for (int hour : notificationHours) {
        if (hour > currentHour) {
            return hour;
         }
    }

    // If no alarm hour is found greater than the current hour,
    // return the first alarm hour in the array (i.e., the next day)
    return notificationHours[0];
}


public static void scheduleNotification() {
    context = MainActivity.getContext();

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int lastScheduledHour = preferences.getInt("lastScheduledHour", -1);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int currentHour = LocalTime.now().getHour();
    int hour = nextAlarmHour(currentHour);

    // Check if the next alarm hour is greater than or equal to the current hour
    if (hour <= currentHour) {
        // Increment the calendar day to the next day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    // Check if the hour is the same as the last scheduled hour
    if (hour == lastScheduledHour) {
        // No need to schedule a duplicate alarm
        return;
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = createNotificationIntent(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Creating notification channel

```
private static void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channelName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Receive notification, and re-schedule

```
public static class MyNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotificationChannel(context);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.xx)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(<text>)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(createStartIntent(context));

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        try {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
        }
        scheduleNotification(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)'s periodic work requests to get around using AlarmManager. It works similarly, but instead of using exact time like AlarmManager, it schedules work by intervals. You can calculate the interval between a specific moment and time of first notification, then fire the worker to start at that interval and repeat at daily intervals.

For example suppose you schedule a periodicworkrequest at 8 AM. You set initial delay to 1hr, with daily intervals. WorkManager isn't exact, so it will start the work a little after 1hr(after 9 AM). You don't need to reschedule them every time unless you want to change intervals, and you can have multiple periodic works running in unison.

Comment: This seems to solve my issues, thanks! Then again it seems like the Samsung implementation of Android kills the WorkManager if the app is cleared from multi-task view, but that seems to be a Samsung issue rather than Android issue

Comment: Samsung Xiaomi and some other OSs do this, it's very annoying. They force stop the app either way.